Error TimeOut when making a screenshot of large page with Selenium (Python)
I have an error when i try to take a screenshot of a large image with Selenium and Python, with Chrome Driver.I tried a lot of thing since yesterday, but i have still the same error. I have the code to take a screenshot, but with a particular page (1050x8100),
i got the error selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 299,800
The versions are ok ( i dont have any errors on other webpages)
Here are the options I've added (after reading several issues on stackoverflow) :
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')  
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')  
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")  
chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')  
chrome_options.add_argument("--force-device-scale-factor=1")

And here is my code to take the screenshot :
self.driver.get(self.url) 
page_width = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollWidth") 
page_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight") self.driver.set_window_size(page_width, page_height) 
time.sleep(10) 
png = self.driver.get_screenshot_as_png() 
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(png)) 
screen_path = os.path.join(folder_output_path, str(number_of_screen) + '.png') image.save(screen_path)

When I set the window size with smaller dimensions, it's running, but I lost information from my page. For a page with:
page_width=1560

and
page_height=7351

it's running, but for page with (1560x8897) it's not working.
Someone can help me to get the screenshot of the whole large page?

Try to reduce the image quality by adding the optimize and quality parameters, this should speed up saving the screenshot, e.g.:
image.save(screen_path, optimize=True, quality=80).
You can also try increasing the timeouts needed to load the page, e.g.
self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(120).

Thanks ! Not working for me, but i suspect my RAM behind this problem ..
